# How is this possible, performing operations on a cell that contains numbers and text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, this is piece of the worksheet. I'm seeing in cell I5, a person managed to perform a division of a H and K2, even though K2 contains a text "us" next to the number.

[image]

Does anyone know how did they manage to do that? Is the "*" that is appended at the end inside each cell relevant?

Thanks

UPDATE:
Hidden columns F, G:

[image]

The "*" column has dropdown "s", "ms", "us". I think they might have converted all units to seconds.

Comment: Custom number format maybe?

Comment: K2 just seems to have 130.446, K5 and down has some text appended. is there an interesting function in K2?

Comment: I updated, the hidden columns

Comment: They are dividing the number in H5 by the number in K2.  K2 is a absolute reference so as the formula is dragged down the H5 will move to H6 but the K2 will always look as K2.  It never looks at K5 through KWhatever.  There is no text in K2

Comment: @Warcupine - yep, 1st thing that jumped to my mind.. despite example in the question being somewhat flawed per SC's comment (only 1 hashtag per msg for some unknown reason..??) 
Notwithstanding, this doesn't negate the possibility of having 'legitimate' functions involving cells that display alphanumeric (I refer to numeric calcs as opposed to string manipulations and so forth of course - and by 'legitimate', I obviously refer to calcs that produce non-eroneous output, although I argue any output can be legitimate depending upon the purpose - though I digress now ) ta

Answer (score -1):

Screenshot(s)/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9hKl8GVYGJWkyEamvRA?e=nHkxJd) refer:

Under certain circumstances you can include/display tex(letters, special/chars etc.) in either/both the cell, formula bar.  Below comprises a (non-exhaustive) list of e.g.'s that spring to mind ()

**1. custom format**

- in e.g. below, value of 2 has format "hello", then "hello" will be displayed in the cell but its value / behaviour will be identical to the underlying value (i.e. 2).
- I have multiplied "We" (val=1, cell: r4), "are" (val = 2, cell s4) and the 'number' "numbers" (u4) to the value 6 U4) to demonstrate..

[image: custom format example]

---

**2. unicode output**

- By definition, unicode(any type) yields an outcome of the numeric type
- Bottom - I take the product of unicode values representing letters of the alphabet in their original form to demonstrate

---

*The following examples relate purely to 'text in formula bar'(n #1, below)*

**3. named ranges**

- Text within formula bar refers to named range

**4. "+n("whatever, whenever, Shakira! ")**

- Convenient for leaving 'insconpicuous' notes or self-reminders / instructions without inserting an entie comment etc.
- Format `cell => <any calc, cell reference, function etc.> + n("hello")`.. *not sure how this functions in arrays/spill type equations though...(?)*

---

[image: Example template]

---

Notes: 3-4 can also be depicted inplace cells with hotkey: *ctrl + `*, per below:

[image: displaying formula with text 'in-place']

---